# Reason for comparing interim_reasons_mask and reasons_mask in CRL Processing

Tags: java, security, x509

In [RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280) in 6.3.3. CRL Processing section there is a step:

> Verify that interim_reasons_mask includes one or more reasons
> that are not included in the reasons_mask.

Could someone explain what's the point of this check. When I try to verify certificate with distribution point pointing to some URL it fails in DistributionPointFetcher:591. reasonsMasks is set to 9 true's so I don't get how is it possible to go through this check cause since it had been initialized it was never changed.

Update

Code where reasons mask is initialized: [Link](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/certpath/RevocationChecker.java#L527)

Code where reasons mask is passed for processing in DistributionPointFetcher: [Link](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/certpath/RevocationChecker.java#L552)

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **reasons_mask:**  This variable contains the set of revocation reasons supported by the CRLs and delta CRLs processed so far.
>
> **interim_reasons_mask:**  This contains the set of revocation reasons supported by the CRL or delta CRL currently being processed.

The purpose of this processing, as far as I can tell, is to gather CRLs to support as many revocation reasons as possible. So it only bothers to add the current CRL to the list if it supports any revocation reasons that weren't supported by any of the previous CRLs.

If your `reasons_mask` contains all `true` then the previous CRLs have covered all revocation reasons, or one doesn't give specific revocation reasons that it supports causing the special value `all-reasons` (all flags true) to be set, meaning that no further revocation reasons need to be covered, thus it doesn't bother checking any further.

---

**sun.security.provider.certpath.DistributionPointFetcher.java**

```
...
// compute interim reasons mask
boolean[] interimReasonsMask = new boolean[9];
ReasonFlags reasons = null;
if (idpExt != null) {
    reasons = (ReasonFlags) idpExt.get(IssuingDistributionPointExtension.REASONS);
}

boolean[] pointReasonFlags = point.getReasonFlags();
if (reasons != null) {
    if (pointReasonFlags != null) {
        // set interim reasons mask to the intersection of
        // reasons in the DP and onlySomeReasons in the IDP
        boolean[] idpReasonFlags = reasons.getFlags();
        for (int i = 0; i < interimReasonsMask.length; i++) {
            interimReasonsMask[i] = (i < idpReasonFlags.length && idpReasonFlags[i])
                    && (i < pointReasonFlags.length && pointReasonFlags[i]);
        }
    } else {
        // set interim reasons mask to the value of
        // onlySomeReasons in the IDP (and clone it since we may
        // modify it)
        interimReasonsMask = reasons.getFlags().clone();
    }
} else if (idpExt == null || reasons == null) {
    if (pointReasonFlags != null) {
        // set interim reasons mask to the value of DP reasons
        interimReasonsMask = pointReasonFlags.clone();
    } else {
        // set interim reasons mask to the special value all-reasons
        Arrays.fill(interimReasonsMask, true);  // ### SEE HERE ###
    }
}

// verify that interim reasons mask includes one or more reasons
// not included in the reasons mask
boolean oneOrMore = false;
for (int i = 0; i < interimReasonsMask.length && !oneOrMore; i++) {
    if (interimReasonsMask[i] && !(i < reasonsMask.length && reasonsMask[i])) {
        oneOrMore = true;
    }
}
if (!oneOrMore) {
    return false;
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I added links to code where reasons_mask is created and passed to DistributionPointFetcher. It's initially set to all-reasons and if there are no  approvedCRLs all-reasons is passed to DistributionPointFetcher. When fetcher fetches CRL from X509 extensions it can't verify them because reasons_mask has all-reasons. As far as I understand the code it just can't work until there are some approvedCRLs already available.

Comment: Ok reasons_mask has 9 false's not true's so I works exactly as you described. Thank you for help.